# How to call an OrientDB function through sails orientdb adapter?

Tags: orientdb, oriento, sails-orientdb

How to run an OrientDB function through the sails-orientdb adapter ?

There is an extension to the waterline method with the signature 
[.runFunction('FunctionName', args...)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-orientdb#runfunction-functionname)  but I cannot get it to work with my use case.

My OrientDB function returns the friends of a given User vertex by it's id :

```
var db = orient.getGraph(); 

return db.command("sql", "select expand(unionall(outE('IsFriendsWith').inV(), inE('IsFriendsWith').outV())) from " + id);
```

My action in the UserController controller calls my orientDB function :

```
findFriends: function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.param('id'));
    User.runFunction('findFriends', '#' + req.param('id')).from('OUser').limit(20).one()
        .then(function (result) {
                res.json(result);
    });
}
```

Am I missing something ?

The console.log(req.param('id')) returns this 33:288786

I get the following logs in the orientdb console :

```
    Cannot serialize record: #-2:0{findFriends:[3]} v0 [ONetworkProtocolBinary]{db=database} Error on unmarshalling record #-2:0 (java.lang.ClassCastException: com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientVertex cannot be cast to com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.ORecord)
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientVertex cannot be cast to com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.ORecord
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerStringAbstract.fieldTypeToString(ORecordSerializerStringAbstract.java:197)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerCSVAbstract.embeddedCollectionToStream(ORecordSerializerCSVAbstract.java:843)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerCSVAbstract.fieldToStream(ORecordSerializerCSVAbstract.java:534)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerSchemaAware2CSV.toString(ORecordSerializerSchemaAware2CSV.java:506)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerStringAbstract.toStream(ORecordSerializerStringAbstract.java:688)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerSchemaAware2CSV.toStream(ORecordSerializerSchemaAware2CSV.java:268)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.toStream(ODocument.java:2102)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.toStream(ODocument.java:714)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.getRecordBytes(OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.java:417)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.writeRecord(OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.java:432)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.writeIdentifiable(OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.java:136)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.command(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:1226)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.executeRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:386)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.execute(OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.java:217)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:69
```

The error tells me that the result needs to be casted to a record ?

I get this result in the OrientDB studio with the id #33:288786 :

```
    [
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#33:288787",
        "@version": 16,
        "@class": "User",
        "gender": false,
        "mail": "1",
        "no": "1",
        "moto": "1",
        "rel": "1",
        "ori": "1",
        "pass": "1",
        "birthDate": null,
        "online": false,
        "name": "1",
        "in_IsFriendsWith": [
            "#23:4"
        ],
        "@fieldTypes": "in_IsFriendsWith=g,"
    }
]
```

I am really clueless on what to do. I just started using sails and waterline as well. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Alex, a few questions: what is the value of `req.param('id')`? Can you add a `console.log()` to check? Does your function work in OrientDB studio/console?

Comment: Yes the function works in the function tab here http://localhost:2480/studio/index.html#/database/database/functions with the id param of #33:288786. The req.param('id') that I am passing to it is this 33:288786 I then add the # at the beginning in the controller action.